# What is the most resistant way to unlock a device

Tags: passwords

The standard way to unlock a device is with a password.  TPMs have improved this to the point that we can create devices that can be unlocked with very short passwords such as PINs and we can create devices that are resistant even in the face of physical access to the device.

However, almost all devices have the flaw that if an adversary observes you unlocking the device one time, the device is completely compromised.  For this reason, Edward Snowden goes under a blanket every time he enters his password.

Is there an alternative that is more convenient?  It doesn't necessarily have to be resistant to cryptanalysis of many observed password entries, but it should resist at least a layperson viewing password entries several times.

If it helps, we could assume that every several logins there is one that is unobserved.

Comment: And if you are talking about unlocking devices, then biometrics have been the proposed solution to PINs for quite a while now. You might need to be more clear about what problem you are trying to solve. You appear to really be asking "how can we improve on PINs to unlock devices that is still usable by the public?"

Comment: @schroeder: Thank you. I rewrote the question. I thought that biometrics were quite insecure?

Comment: Biometrics are not insecure. The readers and the implementation can be insecure.

Comment: "most resistant" -- resistant to what?

Comment: The answer to the question is biometrics and physical passkey. These have been around for quite a while.

Comment: My fingerprints are all over the place including over my devices. And as biometrics are being increasingly adopted, the problem is only going to get worse. Especially because once someone's fingerprints are compromised, there's no changing them.

Comment: Resistant to adversaries. I've mentioned one particular issue that I see— observation.  But I am open to addressing other potential threats.

Comment: You can't design a protection until you define the threat. Biometrics and passkey are resistant to observation. A "layperson" as you have indicated, is not going to easily reproduce fingerprints. So, that is your answer. If you have other threats in mind, then you will need to define them. As it stands, this is an undefined problem.

Comment: There is no absolute measurement of resistance against unlocking a device. Every form of authentication has more and less resistance against a threat. Their combination is what complements weaknesses of each other. 2FA is the most resistant.